# C locale in string.punctuation

Tags: python

Upon reading [string — Common string operations — Python 3.7.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

It states that

> string.punctuation¶
>   String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale.

What does C locale mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `locale` documentation, 'C' is the default locale : https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

It seems that this behaviour is inherited from the C language.